# Expensive left joins onto an empty subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

Novice SQL writer here trying to better understand scheduling and efficient code writing. I'm running a query that's performing very poorly and I don't understand why. We are using SQL Server 2012.

When I run just the subquery (aliased as "te"), it runs in less than a second and returns zero rows (which I expected). But when I run the full query it's taking upwards of a minute. Doesn't an inner join or left outer join onto an empty set always return an empty set? So shouldn't the DB engine figure out that it doesn't need to do any of those joins when the subquery returns no results?

Any recommendations on how to better optimize? What best practices should I remember when writing SQL in the future?

```
INSERT INTO #target_events
   SELECT p.polyname,
          bp.PurposeAbbr,
          s.schid,
          s.ldate,
          es.EvStrId,
          es.evstrname,
          e.evparent,
          e.evid,
          e.Lat / 1000000.0 AS 'Lat',
          e.Lon / 1000000.0 AS 'Lon',
          e.eta,
          e.etd,
          e.PassOn,
          e.PassOnBoard,
          e.Activity,
          e.SchedStatus,
          e.EvClass
   FROM
   (
       SELECT te.*
       FROM #target_events te
            LEFT OUTER JOIN #target_events te2 ON te2.schid = te.schid
                                                  AND te2.EvStrId = te.EvStrId
                                                  AND te2.EvParent = te.EvParent
                                                  AND te2.Activity != te.Activity
       WHERE te.Activity IN(0, 1)
            AND te.SchedStatus = 3
            AND te2.EvId IS NULL
   ) te -- This subquery runs in under 1 second and returns zero rows
   INNER JOIN events e ON e.schid = te.schid
                          AND e.EvStrId = te.EvStrId
                          AND e.EvParent = te.EvParent
                          AND e.Activity != te.Activity
   INNER JOIN eventstrings es ON es.evstrid = e.evstrid
                                 AND es.schid = e.schid
   INNER JOIN schedules s ON s.schid = e.schid
   LEFT OUTER JOIN clients c ON c.clientid = e.clientid
   LEFT OUTER JOIN address a ON a.addrid = c.clientid
                                AND a.AddrType = 'CH' -- Client Home addresses.
   LEFT OUTER JOIN polygons p ON p.polyid = a.jurispolyid
   LEFT OUTER JOIN booking b ON b.bookingid = e.bookingid
   LEFT OUTER JOIN bookingpurpose bp ON bp.purposeid = b.purposeid; -- These joins take a long time...
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` on empty set is empty only if left table is empty. This is the essence of it.

Comment: When an optimizer builds an execution plan it may transform the original query in many ways including changing the order of joins. It can not figure out which part of query will return zero rows at the moment so it can not take this into account when building a plan. If you need to solve a performance problem learn reading execution plans. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: is this b.purposeid indexed?

Comment: When you can't figure out why a query is running slow, the first thing you should do is look at the execution plan.

Comment: Just as an experiment, try adding TOP 4000000000 before te.*.  It's more rows than you will ever have, and the TOP command will force SQL to process the joins on te and te2 before it trying to join anything else.  Since row estimation on temp files can be a bit dicey, it's not out of the question that this could magically trick SQL into generating a much better plan.

Comment: I'm suspicious about the fact that you are inserting into the same table that you are reading from, i.e. `#target_events`.

Comment: How big are the tables you're JOINing on? Do these tables have good indexes on them? Look at the query plan and see where the bottleneck is. You can also simply remove your temp table and run the second half of the query (FROM events table) to see if that query can be run in a reasonable time. It looks like all of the lower JOINs link back to that table anyway.

Comment: @TheEsisia It's just logging a new row if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: @Robert Sievers you're recommendation did trick it into running that subquery first and improved the run time of the full query to <1 second.

Comment: Thank you to @Serg for pointing me to that link regarding the execution plan features. It looks like without the TOP command that Robert Sievers recommended, the query plan performs the three inner joins of the outer query before performing the left outer join of the subquery and then the left outer joins of the outer query. Is the TOP command the only way to get SQL to run the inner query first?